# Can XML be mapped to a SQL Server table in ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

We would like to use Azure Data Factory to read an XML document and be able to map the columns in the document to a SQL Server table so we can move the data contained in the document to a SQL table. Is this possible in ADF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `XML` file type in copy activity is not supported based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs).

I suggest you voting up an [idea](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/17508058-xml-file-type-in-copy-activity-along-with-xml-sc) submitted by another Azure customer.

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

As workarounds,maybe you could get some clues from this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/).

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data factory now supports XML format in both copy activity and mapping data flow.

Learn more from https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/azure-data-factory-adds-support-for-xml-format/ba-p/1529012.